# What VBA validation logic can be added to prevent the user from entering any number greater than 8 in Microsoft Access?

Tags: vba, validation, ms-access

I have a database where employees login their hours taken off or vacation. The numbers to be added should be in hours but when someone takes half an hour break instead of inputting 0.5, they enter 30. I want the database to show an error when they enter anything over 8 hours.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Are they just editing tables directly in Access? Wouldn't you want to have some sort of front-end?

Comment: I have added the validation rule <=8 which works. But if the employee removes the entered data then it still shows the validation text. how do I default the value to zero if they remove it?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a validation rule in the field of a table, or in the textbox of a form, to force data being `<=8`. We do not know if users access the data trough a form or directly into table, but this will work in both cases.

> To know more how Validation Rules check:**[Restrict data input by
>   using validation
>   rules](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/restrict-data-input-by-using-validation-rules-b91c6b15-bcd3-42c1-90bf-e3a0272e988d?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US)**

Comment: This worked well but my only issue is if the employee removes the entered data then it still shows the validation text. how do I default the value to zero if they remove it?

Answer (score 0):

To streamline this, you can use an *input mask* like:

```
"90:00;1;0"
```

and some code like:

```
Private Sub Logon_KeyPress(KeyAscii As Integer)

    Dim Text        As String
    Dim Char        As String
    Dim Length      As Integer
    Dim SelStart    As Integer

    With Me!Logon
        Select Case KeyAscii
            Case vbKeyBack, vbKeyTab, Asc(vbLf), vbKeyReturn, vbKeyEscape, vbKeyF16
                ' Allow navigation etc. with
                ' BackSpace, Tab, Ctrl+Enter, Enter, Escape, Ctrl+BackSpace
            Case Is > 0
                Text = .Text
                Length = Len(Text)
                SelStart = .SelStart

                If KeyAscii < vbKey0 Or KeyAscii > vbKey9 Then
                    ' Replace any invalid entry with a zero.
                    KeyAscii = vbKey0
                End If

                Char = Mid(Text, 1 + SelStart, 1)
                If SelStart < Length Then
                    If KeyAscii <= vbKey0 + 2 Then
                        ' Always accept 0, 1, 2.
                    Else
                        ' Check if the text will represent a valid time.
                        ' If not, restore the overwritten digit.
                        Mid(Text, 1 + SelStart, 1) = Chr(KeyAscii)
                        If Not IsDate(Text) Then
                            DoCmd.Beep
                            KeyAscii = Asc(Char)
                        End If
                    End If
                End If
        End Select
    End With

End Sub
```

To polish it, some more code is needed. It is all described in my article and demo:

[Entering 24-hour time with input mask and full validation in Microsoft Access](https://www.experts-exchange.com/articles/23539/Entering-24-hour-time-with-input-mask-and-full-validation-in-Microsoft-Access.html)

If you don't have an account, browse to the link: *Read the full article*

Code is also on **GitHub**: [VBA.TimeEntry](https://github.com/GustavBrock/VBA.TimeEntry)